# FFserver: cannot connect via rtsp

Tags: networking, ffmpeg, rtsp, ffserver

so im currrently trying to stream my windows desktop using ffmpeg into a raspberry pi running ffserver. 
The client software im using needs to use RTSP, however i cannot connect to the stream no matter what i try. 
I even used VLC in the messages it just says it cannot connect to the stream. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Im attempting to access the stream with rtsp  ://   169.254.70.227   :8544/test.flv, as soon as i do it stops the ffmpeg feed

FFserver conf

```
`RTSPPort 8544
HTTPPort 8090                      # Port to bind the server to
HTTPBindAddress 0.0.0.0
MaxHTTPConnections 2000
MaxClients 1000
MaxBandwidth 10000             # Maximum bandwidth per client
                               # set this high enough to exceed stream bitrate
CustomLog -                       # Remove this if you want FFserver to daemoni$

<Feed feed1.ffm>               # This is the input feed where FFmpeg will send
   File ./feed1.ffm            # video stream.
   FileMaxSize 100000K              # Maximum file size for buffering video
   ACL allow 192 .168.0.8
   ACL allow 192 .168.0.17
   ACL allow 169 .254.70.227
   ACL allow 169 .254.9.29
   ACL allow 169 .254.165.231
   ACL allow 10 .14.2.197
   ACL allow 192 .168.0.13
   ACL allow 10 .14.2.197
   ACL allow 192.16 8.0.13
   ACL allow 192.1 68.1.3
   ACL allow 192. 168.1.4
   ACL allow 192 .168.1.2
</Feed>

<Stream test.flv>                       # Output stream URL definition
   Format rtp
   Feed feed1.ffm
NoAudio

   # Video settings
   VideoCodec libx264
   VideoSize 720x576           # Video resolution
VideoBufferSize 2000

 VideoFrameRate 30           # Video FPS
    # Parameters passed to encoder
   AVOptionVideo qmin 10
   AVOptionVideo qmax 42

   PreRoll 15
   StartSendOnKey
MulticastAddress 224 .124.0.1
MulticastPort 5000
MulticastTTL 16
   VideoBitRate 450            # Video bitrate
</Stream>

<Stream status.html>                    # Server status URL
   Format status
   # Only allow local people to get the status
   ACL allow localhost
  # Only allow local people to get the status
   ACL allow localhost
   ACL allow 192.168. 0.0 192.168. 255.255
</Stream>

<Redirect index. html>    # Just an URL redirect for index
   # Redirect index.html to the appropriate site
   URL http   ://www.  ffmpeg .org/
</Redirect>`
```

FFmpeg feed

```
ffmpeg -rtbufsize 2100M -f dshow -r 29.970 -i video=screen-capture-recorder -c video=screen-capture-recorder.flv http  ://  169 .254.70.227:8090/ feed1.ffm
```

FFserver output

```
  configuration: --arch=armel --target-os=linux --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      55. 22.101 / 55. 22.101
  libavcodec     57. 35.100 / 57. 35.100
  libavformat    57. 34.103 / 57. 34.103
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 44.100 /  6. 44.100
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
/etc/ffserver.conf:48: Setting default value for video bit rate tolerance = 112500. Use NoDefaults to disable it.
/etc/ffserver.conf:48: Setting default value for video rate control equation = tex^qComp. Use NoDefaults to disable it.
/etc/ffserver.conf:48: Setting default value for video max rate = 20744848. Use NoDefaults to disable it.
Wed Apr 27 10:33:46 2016 FFserver started.
Wed Apr 27 10:33:46 2016 224.124.0.1:5000 - - "PLAY test.flv/streamid=0 RTP/MCAST"
Wed Apr 27 10:33:46 2016 [rtp @ 0x13d4660]Using AVStream.codec to pass codec parameters to muxers is deprecated, use AVStream.codecpar instead.
Wed Apr 27 10:33:49 2016 169.254.165.231 - - [GET] "/feed1. ffm HTTP/1.1" 200 4175
```

FFMpeg output

```
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 000000000252f5e0] Warning: data is not aligned! This can lead to a speedloss
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Unknown errortime=00:00:05.00 bitrate= 249.0kbits/s speed=0.393x
Error writing trailer of http:  //169. 254.70.227:8090/feed1.ffm: Error number -10053 occurredframe=  204 fps= 15 q=26.0 Lsize=     164kB time=00:00:05.03 bitrate= 266.9kbits/s speed=0.365x
video:155kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 5.475512%
[libx264 @ 00000000025187e0] frame I:1     Avg QP:34.24  size: 32151
[libx264 @ 00000000025187e0] frame P:59    Avg QP:27.14  size:  1807
[libx264 @ 00000000025187e0] frame B:144   Avg QP:32.16  size:   168
[libx264 @ 00000000025187e0] consecutive B-frames:  4.9%  2.0%  2.9% 90.2%
[libx264 @ 00000000025187e0] mb I  I16..4: 26.0% 23.1% 50.9%
[libx264 @ 00000000025187e0] mb P  I16..4:  1.9%  1.6%  1.1%  P16..4:  4.3%  0.6%  0.4%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:90.2%
[libx264 @ 00000000025187e0] mb B  I16..4:  0.2%  0.1%  0.1%  B16..8:  3.1%  0.1%  0.0%  direct: 0.1%  skip:96.3%  L0:26.0% L1:73.5% BI: 0.5%
[libx264 @ 00000000025187e0] final ratefactor: 24.13
[libx264 @ 00000000025187e0] 8x8 transform intra:31.8% inter:47.1%
[libx264 @ 00000000025187e0] coded y,u,v intra: 28.1% 8.2% 6.3% inter: 0.6% 0.2% 0.1%
[libx264 @ 00000000025187e0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 30% 63%  6%  1%
[libx264 @ 00000000025187e0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 16% 16% 63%  1%  0%  0%  1%  0%  3%
[libx264 @ 00000000025187e0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 28% 39% 15%  2%  2%  3%  4%  3%  4%
[libx264 @ 00000000025187e0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 00000000025187e0] ref P L0: 66.3% 13.1% 16.9%  3.6%
[libx264 @ 00000000025187e0] ref B L0: 66.6% 29.7%  3.8%
[libx264 @ 00000000025187e0] ref B L1: 91.7%  8.3%
[libx264 @ 00000000025187e0] kb/s:191.78
Conversion failed!
```